# Text disappears on slider on mobile

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I'm having trouble finding out why or how to fix the nivo-slider text from disappearing on the mobile view of the site. It displays fine for desktop and tablet sizes.

http://www.cooldownjuice.com/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried both 

`@media (max-width: 480px) {
.slider_wrap {
    height: auto;
}
}`


`@media (max-width: 480px) {
#wrapper2 {
    height: auto;
}
}`

and nothing is working..

Comment: Try adding !important

Comment: actually just figured it out myself. display was set to none in a separate css file.. all fixed.